# ST_DWithin() Point to Polygon - What is referenced?

Tags: postgis

I have a Point geometry and several Polygons surrounding the point geometry. If I use the `ST_DWithin()` function and give it, lets say - 500m as a parameter. What Polygons return true?
The Polygons that would intersect with a 500m buffer around the point geometry. Or the polygons that have their centroid within the 500m buffer of the point geometry? Or the polygons that are completly within the 500m radius of the point geometry?
I hope you understand what I am aiming at.

Comment: Alternative "intersect with a 500m buffer around the point geometry", just like ST_Distance works. But interesting that I could not easily find where it is explained.

Comment: @user30184 Yes I did not find any information on this. Thats why I asked here!

Comment: Those polygons that have any *point set* or *ring segment* (vector) distance of equal or less than 500m to the point, or have the point *intersect its interior*.

Comment: The latter condition feels unnecessary. If the point intersects the interior of the polygon (thus, is within), the distance=0.

Comment: @user30184 yes, but your *"the distance"* is a context based predicate; in terms of vector distance, a point inside a polygon has a distance to the boundary of likely greater than 0. You can either determine if it is left or right compared to winding order, or do an intersection test. PostGIS does the former on the point pair segments of each ring (starting with the boundary)

Comment: I do not have my own definitions but I try to find out what OGC has defined. In the Simple Feature Access standard the distance is defined this way "Distance (anotherGeometry: Geometry):Double — Returns the shortest distance between any two Points in the two geometric objects as calculated in the spatial reference system of this geometric object. Because the geometries are closed, it is possible to find a point on each geometric object involved, such that the distance between these 2 points is the returned distance between their geometric objects."

Comment: @user30184 I was referring to how this is projected in low-level vector math, where it is necessary to determine if the point is inside the polygon first, in order to then *declare* it to be at distance = 0. The high level definition you stated is correct, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OpenGIS Filter Encoding Implementation Specification http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-026r2/09-026r2.html DWithin is defined this way:

> The spatial operators DWithin and Beyond test whether the value of a
> geometric property is within or beyond a specified distance of the
> specified literal geometric value. Distance values are expressed using
> the <Distance> element. The content of the <Distance> element
> represents the magnitude of the distance and the units attribute is
> used to specify the units of measure.

I found a nice description from https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Geospatial/STV_DWithin.htm?

> Determines if the shortest distance from the boundary of one spatial
> object to the boundary of another object is within a specified
> distance.

EDIT Unfortunately I think that this description that considers only boundaries is wrong if one object is within another object.

It is to be noted that the distance from a polygon to a point that is inside the polygon is always zero.

[image]

This returns 0

```
select ST_Distance(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((3 21, 4 20, 2 20, 3 21))'),
ST_GeomFromText('POINT (3 20.5)'));
```

But this returns 0.35355

```
select ST_Distance(ST_Boundary(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((3 21, 4 20, 2 20, 3 21))')),
ST_GeomFromText('POINT (3 20.5)'));
```